# Visual Studio 2015 frozen and unresponsive when debugging cordova app

Tags: .net, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I'm running a cordova app on visual studio 2015, using the latest CTP (3) and the ripple emulator for chrome.
Everything fine until I try to debug. Even though the application loads, visual studio freezes and the debugger is in a weird mode

[image]

Even if I click the "refresh" stuff it still doesn't debug, and gets unresponsive from time to time. 
Any other debugging works well (standard .net console app, etc.)
Does anyone know why this could be happening and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The Ripple emulator does not allow for proper debugging when Chrome is run as an administrator. Since you have run VS as an admin, Chrome will be as well. The best way to fix this issue is to do the following steps:

1. Close VS
2. Open the Task Manager, and kill any remaining node.exe and chrome.exe processes
3. Start VS non-elevated

Comment: Note - we will ship a fix for this in a future update (disclaimer: I work for Microsoft)

Comment: i've run VS as admin out of desperation, i've already tried the same thing without it running as admin :(

Comment: Hi @MichaelBraude, I've tried the proposed solution but the same behavior happens. I'm using visual studio 2015. Any ideas how I can troubleshoot the issue?. Thanks!

Comment: I can't quite tell from your post... Which version of visual studio / Cordova are you using? Is it ctp 3 or rtm? Are you on update 4 of Cordova?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2013 ultimate with update 4 (12.0.31101.00) and visual studio tools for apache cordova version 0.3.22015.1